# Capturing output from Perl's require

Tags: perl

Is it possible to capture output from Perl's require?

For example:

```
{
    local @ARGV = qw/ hello world /;
    require 'myscript.pl';
}
```

Id like to capture any stdout that `myscript.pl` generates. Can imagine something like this:

```
{
    local @ARGV = qw/ hello world /;
    my $output = require 'myscript.pl';
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish? `require` loads a module. There are other approaches if you want to `run` a script.

Comment: There's `my $output = qx{myscript.pl}` if you don't need to load the subroutines from the file, which is what `require` is for. But please explain your circumstance as [Sobrique](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2566198/sobrique) has asked

Comment: Note that `require` won't load the same file twice, so `require 'myscript.pl'` may well be a no-op and not produce any output.

Comment: You caught me.. I was going to use this as a way to run perl scripts, without spawning a subprocess; spawning off the calls as system calls kills me for running the code in the debugger, and getting code coverage statistics when writing tests.

Comment: ... if I change my `require` to a `do`, would that be a reasonable way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) makes this easier:

```
use Capture::Tiny 'capture_stdout';

my $output = capture_stdout {
    local @ARGV = qw/hello world/;
    require 'foo.pl';
};
```

although I would agree that this is generally not a good way to run a script.

Comment: Would it be an OK way to run a script if the `require` was a `do`?

Comment: @ajwood not really. The fact that you're not starting a new process is the problem (or at least, the danger). In some cases you might get away with it, but sharing global state like that is usually the source of hard-to-debug issues.

Comment: I'm kind of pinned into a corner with the design of this software system. It's a collection of Perl scripts, which call Perl scripts, which call Perl scripts.. Execution profiling, or test coverage, etc, goes dark after the first system call. I was hoping I could somehow get everything to run in the top Perl instance.

Comment: @ajwood If you ask a new question and explain your actual problem in detail, you might get better solutions.

Comment: @ajwood - You can, and it might work fine. I won't tell you not to. Just be aware of what you're getting into :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.  You need to redirect `STDOUT` before `require`ing and restore the original `STDOUT` afterwards.

a.pl

```
my $capture;
open STDOUTBACKUP, '>&STDOUT';
close STDOUT;
open STDOUT, '>', \$capture;
require 'b.pl';
close STDOUT;
open STDOUT, '>&STDOUTBACKUP';
print "CAPTURED: $capture";
```

b.pl

```
print "ModuleB";
```

Output is `CAPTURED: ModuleB`

Answer (score 0):

`myscript.pl` appears to be a Perl script. It makes no sense to use `require` or `do`.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote('myscript.pl', 'hello', 'world');
my $output = `$cmd`;
die("Can't execute myscript.pl: $!\n")                  if $? == -1;
die("myscript.pl killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
die("myscript.pl returned error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n")     if $? >> 8;
```

or

```
open(my $pipe, '-|', 'myscript.pl', 'hello', 'world')
   or die("Can't execute myscript.pl: $!\n");

my $output = '';
$output .= $_ while <$pipe>;
close($pipe);
die("myscript.pl killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
die("myscript.pl returned error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n")     if $? >> 8;
```

Comment: I'm going to ask a new question to address my actual issue.. but take a look at the comments on hobbs' answer. My problem is that the execution isn't accessible to the debugger, code performance profiling, execution coverage etc..

Comment: All of those things need to be requested. Feel free to request them.